# Struts2 form parameters with same name and retrieving the values

Tags: struts2

I've an input fields dynamically added multiple times in the form using jQuery. Onsubmit of the form, at the action side I'm getting **"comma+space"** separated request parameters & values as shown below,

```
<input type="text" name="chars" />
```

Action side --> chars=char1, char2, char3,......

to get the values I can split the string by comma(,), but this case fails if the user enters comma in the text fields. I cannot get the entered comma by any means.

Can anyone suggest on how to separate the values and get the comma as character as I've to store this in DB?

Comment: Just use list as of type of your `chars` variable in your action.

Comment: And do not read the request parameter, just declare the private List<Character> with Getter and Setter in the Action

Comment: we can even split the string like this --> chars.split(", ");